# Magento2, Is it still necessary to disable a module before uninstalling it, and setup:upgrade? Any idea why this can't be the one command?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

To disable a Magento2 module, I do the following.

```
php bin/magento module:disable <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> --clear-static-content
php bin/magento module:uninstall <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> -r
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Is there any reason this can't be part of the uninstall procedure? What problems are preventing better solutions right now?  What needs to be improved to make the abstractions less leaky?

Comment: Stupid but does the job for me. Join all commands with && and hit enter ;)

Comment: It does, I'd really just like to know what barriers prevent improvement, because I find it hard to believe it's all this bad across the board because people didn't feel like helping.  Obviously if no barrier exists, I'd join the effort to correct things.